# App icon not showing in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

CHROME: [image: chrome]

SAFARI: [image: safari]

BOTH: [image: Both]

I did not change my app icon assets whatsoever from my previous build(s), and have submitted at least 10 builds before without this issue. Also, per another SO answer, I submitted this app for review and it has been several hours and the icon still will not appear.

Is this an Apple problem, or am I doing something wrong in Xcode/iTunes Connect?

*Note my app has already been reviewed and approved 3 times by Apple, but the icon has always shown up in Connect

**Edit:** I was able to produce this strange message when I right clicked and opened the "image" in a new tab:

```
{"code":{"code":"1","name":"Unknown"},"errorMessage":"An unexpected exception occurred.  (correlation key: WORFP57ERM7J22VY2RDKSYWNV4)","correlationKey":"WORFP57ERM7J22VY2RDKSYWNV4"}
```

Comment: Are you using safari?

Comment: Chrome, but I also tried viewing on Safari. Same problem.

Comment: Are you on windows? It shouldn't happen... right click on the icon and open in new tab if it shows.

Comment: No, I'm on a mac running Yosemite. I added a screenshot to show how it looks in Safari. Can't click on it, or open in new tab.

Comment: I was able to get a strange message though, check my edit above.

Comment: I had this happen twice now and it suddenly showed up after a few hours.

Comment: Thanks Anton, good to know. Hoping this will be the case. Starting to worry though since it's been almost 5 hours...

Comment: I can confirm @Anton's comment. Had the same problem several times, does not matter since it fixes itself after some time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a problem / bug inside iTunesConnect. It will show up eventually, no need to worry. (I know that from experience.)

Comment: I hope you're right. Six hours later and still no icon is appearing. Will mark correct as soon as it does!

Comment: Well, Apple will complain when reviewing that the icon is missing if it actually is. If they don't then you can be pretty sure it's there :) (you might want to think about putting that as comment in the reviewNotes.)

Comment: After nearly a day, the app icon finally appeared. Was starting to panic. Thanks Linus & Anton.

Comment: Glad everything's fine :)