# iTunesConnect iOS App with question mark where there should be the app's logo

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I submitted an iOS app and there is a question mark in place of where the app logo should be in iTunesConnect -> My Apps -> app_name -> Prerelease -> Builds:

[image]

Then under the versions tab (iTunesConnect -> My Apps -> app_name -> Prerelease -> Versions) the app icon is blank in the "Build" section after selecting the build:

[image]

Additionally, the app icon is blank when using TestFlight:

[image]

While installing with TestFlight, the app shows the default blueprint icon Apple uses when apps do not have icons. After finishing installation, the app icon shows up and everything works as expected.

My worry is somehow the application will reach the App Store without the logo showing. I understand the icon is part of the app bundle and there should be no way for the app to reach the App Store without an icon since there are usually warnings given during submission via Xcode. However, this happens on each submission to iTunesConnect. I assume this is an internal error by Apple but would love to know if anyone else has come across this issue and knows how to fix it. Thanks!

(The build and version are blacked out intentionally)

Notes:

Xcode Version 6.2,
Supports iOS 7 and iOS 8

**UPDATE**

When copying the image's url and pasting it into Safari, I get the following JSON:

```
{
    "code":
    {
        "code": "1",
        "name": "Unknown"
    },
    "correlationKey": "ITH2ELJLYV3QC6WBXIR4HUIYJM",
    "errorMessage": "An unexpected exception occurred.  (correlation key: ITH2ELJLYV3QC6WBXIR4HUIYJM)"
}
```

Comment: Sometimes it takes a bit for the icon to show. I know in particular my OSX apps don't have the Icon properly display until it's processed. I'm thinking maybe your binary hasn't been processed yet. Give it an hour or two, if the problem persists contact Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes it takes a bit for the icon to show. I know in particular my OSX apps don't have the Icon properly display until it's processed. I'm thinking maybe your binary hasn't been processed yet. Give it an hour or two, if the problem persists contact Apple.

And don't worry about it being submitted without a logo to the app store. Apple are sticklers for perfection and uniformity with their apps. If your screenshot or icon is even slightly off they will reject your binary!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A similar answer was given to the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606424/app-icon-not-showing-in-itunes-connect